# Angular Observable data lost on refresh, is there way to save data even after refresh

Tags: angular, observable, refresh

I am using `BehaviourSubject` from Shared Service whenever I refresh the page I am getting null as a response, it loses the last emit event data

Comment: Please share some code!!!!

Comment: SPAs on refresh will initiate the process from the start. So anything that's stored in a variable will be reset. If there's something that's not going through constructors and NgOnInit then it will not retain its value. Unless of course stored in local storage

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain a value of a `BehaviourSubject` even after refresh one approach could be to use localStorage and retrieving value when component loads:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private localKey="myVal";
  myVal = new BehaviorSubject(localStorage.getItem(this.localKey)??null);
  ngOnInit(){
    this.myVal.subscribe(newVal=>{
      localStorage.setItem(this.localKey,newVal);
    })
  }
}
```

[stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qk687z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

*Because localStorage stores value only in form of string, you can only store  literals (except symbols) or plain Object/arrays having literals (you need to stringify and parse in JSON format for them).*